# cs50 speller : when debugging I found that my while loop in load isn't executing

Tags: c, cs50

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
// TODO
FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary,"r");

if (dict == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
//initialize table
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    table[i] = NULL;
}
//char array
char word[LENGTH + 1];
//read from file

while(fscanf(dict,"%s\n",word) != EOF)
{
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    /* so we know where the end of the linked list is */
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't malloc new node\n");
        fclose(dict);
        return false;
    }
    /*hash table*/
    strcpy(new_node->word , word);
    hash_value = hash(word);

    if(table[hash_value] == NULL)
    {
        table[hash_value] = new_node;
    }else
    {
        new_node -> next = table[hash_value];
        table[hash_value] = new_node;
    }
    word_count++;
}
fclose(dict);
return true;
}
```

I've tried everything i can't seem to find whats wrong. Am I assigning my file incorrectly or is my implementation of fscanf wrong ? I tried debugging with debugg50 and i found that my while loop wasn't executing at all.

Comment: Don't use trailing spaces (like newline) in your `scanf` formats. It's almost never needed, and can often cause problems.

Comment: Please show a [mre] so that we don't have to guess what the needed declarations and driver code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. Don't use `fscanf` (and don't compare against `EOF`).
2. `cs50` dictionary files have only *one* word per line.
3. Use `fgets` and then `strcspn` to remove the newline.
4. You're dereferencing `new_node` (with `new_node->next = NULL;`) *before* you check it for `NULL`
5. If your `hash` function does not use `% N`, you should do that in the caller.
6. Your `table` setting logic can be simplified. No need to special case a `NULL` value for `table[hash_value]`

For some additional help, please see my cs50 speller answer: [cs50 pset5 Speller optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316468/5382650)

Here is the cleaned up code:

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (dict == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    //initialize table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    //char array
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    //read from file
    while (fgets(word,sizeof(word),dict) != NULL) {
        // strip newline
        word[strcspn(word,"\n")] = 0;

        if (new_node == NULL) {
            printf("Couldn't malloc new node\n");
            fclose(dict);
            return false;
        }

        // copy value into node
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);

        // compute the hash
        hash_value = hash(word);
        hash_value %= N;

        new_node->next = table[hash_value];
        table[hash_value] = new_node;

        word_count++;
    }

    fclose(dict);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Only other thing I usually mention is how the default `N` is woefully inadequate. So much so you don't really have a hash-table but more a collection of linked lists. And finally how the hash-table *Load-Factor* shouldn't exceed 70% (60% is more ideal) being the number of `buckets filled / total buckets`, or here `words in dict / N` (presuming a decent hash algorithm with few if any collisions for words)