# CS50 Week 5 Speller solution

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50

I ran check 50 on this code and I got all green smilies, including the one that says the program is free of memory errors.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

int total_words = 0;

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 45;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int hash_val;
    node *ptr = NULL;

    hash_val = hash(word);

    ptr=table[hash_val];

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(word, ptr->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    return toupper(word[0]) - 'A';
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    int state = 1;
    char buffer[LENGTH+1];
    int hash_val;
    int i = 0;
    node *ptr = NULL;

    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
        return false;
    }
    while(state != 0)
    {
        state = fscanf(file,"%s",buffer);
        if(state != 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if(n == NULL)
        {
            fclose(file);
            unload();
            return false;
        }

        n->next = NULL;
        i = 0;

        while(buffer[i] != '\0')
        {
            n->word[i] = buffer[i];
            i++;
        }
        n->word[i] = buffer[i];

        hash_val = hash(n->word);

        n->next = table[hash_val];
        table[hash_val] = n;

    }


    for(int j = 0; j<26; j++)
    {

        ptr=table[j];
        while(ptr != NULL)
        {
        total_words++;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return true;

}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return total_words;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    int fake = 0;
    node *ptr = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;

    for(int j = 0; j<26; j++)
    {
        temp=table[j];

        if(temp != NULL)
        {
            ptr = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = ptr;
        }
        free(temp);
    }

    return true;
}
```

but when I ran valgrind on it, it gave me this error message

```
==2682== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2682==     in use at exit: 8,010,184 bytes in 143,039 blocks
==2682==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 57 frees, 8,023,256 bytes allocated
==2682== 
==2682== 8,008,728 bytes in 143,013 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==2682==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2682==    by 0x109A36: load (dictionary.c:83)
==2682==    by 0x1092BB: main (speller.c:40)
==2682== 
==2682== 8,010,184 (1,456 direct, 8,008,728 indirect) bytes in 26 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==2682==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2682==    by 0x109A36: load (dictionary.c:83)
==2682==    by 0x1092BB: main (speller.c:40)
==2682== 
==2682== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2682==    definitely lost: 1,456 bytes in 26 blocks
==2682==    indirectly lost: 8,008,728 bytes in 143,013 blocks
==2682==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2682==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2682==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2682== 
==2682== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==2682== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Valgrind gave me that message because I only free the first 2 nodes in each linked list but check50 says its fine. Is this a bug in their checking algorithm or is it ok to leak memory for speller because im pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: Leaking memory is almost always not ok. I'd trust Valgrind over CS50's memory checker.

Comment: How are we supposed to be able to help when you haven't included the code for which it report leaks?

Comment: @squash_II  Post definition of  `LENGTH`.  Even better a [mcve]/

Comment: FWIW: Notice that check50 (presumably) uses the small dictionary for the memory leak test, which is consistent with "_Valgrind gave me that message because I only free the first 2 nodes in each linked list_"

Answer (score 1):

Since not all code was provided, I'm unable to test this solution.

The `unload` function is incorrect.

1. The `for` loop goes only to 26 but should go to `N`
2. It only does `free` on the *first* element of the linked list from a given `table[j]`. The `if` should be a `while`
3. The last `free` is incorrect

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool
unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    int fake = 0;
    node *ptr = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;

// NOTE/BUG: there are N hash buckets, not just 26
#if 0
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
#else
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
#endif
        temp = table[j];

// NOTE/BUG: this only frees the _first_ element of the linked list
#if 0
        if (temp != NULL) {
#else
        while (temp != NULL) {
#endif
            ptr = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = ptr;
        }

// NOTE/BUG: when corrected above, this free is extraneous.
#if 0
        free(temp);
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: we should clear this if we wish to reuse/refill the hash table
#if 1
        table[j] = NULL;
#endif
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is a slightly cleaned up version:

```
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool
unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    node *ptr;
    node *temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (temp = table[j];  temp != NULL;  temp = ptr) {
            ptr = temp->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        table[j] = NULL;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

For some additional guidance/suggestions, see my cs50 speller answer: [cs50 pset5 Speller optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316468/5382650)

Comment: I know the correct solution and submitted it, which is accurate according to both valgrind (which reports that there are no memory leaks) and check50. However, the code I posted above meets cs50's requirements but valgrind reports that I lost practically all my allocated memory. I was wondering if memory leaks are fine for this problem set or if their check algorithm is wrong. This can only really be tested by someone enrolled in cs50 as for the rest of the code it is cs50 'distribution' code, meaning it comes with the problem set.