# Frowny face for cs50 pset 5 "handles most basic words properly" and "spell-checking is case-insensitive"

Tags: c, cs50, edx

I ran check50 and I got a frowny face for "spell-checking is case-insensitive" and "handles most basic words properly."

How could I fix this? Does it have to do with my hash function?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of words in dictionary
int word_count = 0;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int n = hash(word);

    node *cursor = table[n];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// Function credit to staff on CS50 reddit page
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
         hash_value = (hash_value << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    return hash_value % N; 
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary and check for memory issue
    //Function guide credit to CS50 Guide by Anvea on YouTube
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Check for memory issue with dict
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Dictionary is null\n");
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(n->word, word);
        word_count++;

        // Index word using hash function
        int dict_index = hash(word);

        // Insert into hash table if already empty
        if (table[dict_index] == NULL)
        {
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        // Insert work as new node if not empyty
        else
        {
            n->next = table[dict_index];
        }

        table[dict_index] = n;
    }

    // Close dictionary file
    fclose(dict);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];

        while (cursor)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First step would be to look closer at the test result from CS50. Does it mention which words were noch handled correctly? (You might also put a link to the the check results into your question.) When you know the affected words, create your own test case for these words and step through your code. Watch your variables change while you step.

Comment: Think... If "bus" is in the dictionary, its hash value will reflect it being lower case. When your program is checked, "BUS" is in the word list. Its hash will reflect it being uppercase. So, BUS won't be found in the place where you've stored "bus"... A bit more work to do... Write a small test program. Give it "bus" and have it report the hash value. Then give it "BUS" and notice the difference...

Comment: Indeed, so if you are lucky, `... ^ tolower(word[i])` inside the hash function might be the only necessary fix.

Comment: Actually, make that `... ^ tolower((unsigned char) word[i])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. All dictionary words are lowercase, one per line. So, the hash is done on lowercase characters.
2. But, the check text can be uppercase. In `check`, it calls `hash` on the mixed case text, so it can generate different hash values for certain words (e.g.) `Won't this work?` and `No, it won't.`
3. In `check`, we need to lowercase the string *before* calling `hash` so we get the *same* hash value/index. As a beneficial side effect of this, we can replace `strcasecmp` with `strcmp` (which is faster).
4. In `load`, there is *no* need to have a special case for when `table[n]` is `NULL`, so we can simplify this.
5. Although I didn't check this, in `hash` doing `<<` may produce a hash value that isn't evenly distributed, slowing down the search in `check`.
6. Because the dictionary file is [guaranteed to be] all lowercase and one entry per line, in `load`, we can replace `fscanf` with `fgets` [stripping the newline] as `fgets` is much faster.
7. With `gcc` 8.3.1, the compiler flagged `node *table[N];` because of: `const unsigned int N = 26;` Unlike C++, this isn't allowed in C--it requires a literal constant and *not* just `const`. So, I changed this to `enum { N = 26 };`
8. *Style note:* Never do (e.g.): `x -> y` instead of `x->y`.

---

Here is the corrected code. I've checked it against all possible input files and dictionaries. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#if 1
#include <ctype.h>
#endif

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Number of words in dictionary
int word_count = 0;

// Number of buckets in hash table
// NOTE/BUG: C (vs C++) doesn't support global arrays from const
#if 0
const unsigned int N = 26;
#else
enum {
    N = 26
};
#endif

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// locase -- copy lower cased word
void
locase(char *dst,const char *src)
{

    for (;  *src != 0;  ++src, ++dst)
        *dst = tolower((unsigned char) *src);
    *dst = 0;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool
check(const char *word)
{
// NOTE/FIX: we _must_ take lowercase of word _before_ calculating the hash
// otherwise, the hash value will differ for uppercase words here and lowercase
// words in the dictionary (i.e. different hash buckets)
// NOTE/FIX: we should convert test word to lowercase _once_ (it allows us to
// use strcmp below)
#if 1
    char lobuf[LENGTH + 1];
    locase(lobuf,word);
    word = lobuf;
#endif
    unsigned int n = hash(word);

    node *cursor = table[n];

    while (cursor != NULL) {
// NOTE/BUG: strcasecmp is very slow compared to strcmp
#if 0
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
            return true;
#else
        if (strcmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
            return true;
#endif
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// Function credit to staff on CS50 reddit page
unsigned int
hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;

#if 0
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
        hash_value = (hash_value << 2) ^ word[i];
#endif
#if 0
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++)
        hash_value = (hash_value << 2) ^ word[i];
#endif
#if 1
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++)
        hash_value = (hash_value * 31) ^ word[i];
#endif

    return hash_value % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary and check for memory issue
    // Function guide credit to CS50 Guide by Anvea on YouTube
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
#if 0
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
#else
    char word[LENGTH + 10];
#endif

    // Check for memory issue with dict
    if (dict == NULL) {
        printf("Dictionary is null\n");
        unload();
        return false;
    }

// NOTE/BUG: dictionary is guaranteed to be one word per line and fscanf is
// slow compared to fgets
#if 0
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF) {
#else
    while (1) {
        if (fgets(word,sizeof(word),dict) == NULL)
            break;
        char *cp = strchr(word,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
#endif

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (n == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(n->word, word);

        word_count++;

        // Index word using hash function
        int dict_index = hash(word);

// NOTE/BUG: no need to special case this
#if 0
        // Insert into hash table if already empty
        if (table[dict_index] == NULL) {
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        // Insert work as new node if not empyty
        else {
            n->next = table[dict_index];
        }
#else
        n->next = table[dict_index];
#endif

        table[dict_index] = n;
    }

    // Close dictionary file
    fclose(dict);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int
size(void)
{
    return word_count;
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool
unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        node *cursor = table[i];

        while (cursor) {
            node *tmp = cursor;

            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the cleaned up version (run through `unifdef -k` with some comment cleanup):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Number of words in dictionary
int word_count = 0;

// Number of buckets in hash table
enum {
    N = 26
};

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// locase -- copy lower cased word
void
locase(char *dst,const char *src)
{

    for (;  *src != 0;  ++src, ++dst)
        *dst = tolower((unsigned char) *src);
    *dst = 0;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool
check(const char *word)
{
    char lobuf[LENGTH + 1];
    locase(lobuf,word);
    word = lobuf;
    unsigned int n = hash(word);

    node *cursor = table[n];

    while (cursor != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
            return true;
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// Function credit to staff on CS50 reddit page
unsigned int
hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++)
        hash_value = (hash_value * 31) ^ word[i];

    return hash_value % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary and check for memory issue
    // Function guide credit to CS50 Guide by Anvea on YouTube
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[LENGTH + 10];

    // Check for memory issue with dict
    if (dict == NULL) {
        printf("Dictionary is null\n");
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    while (1) {
        if (fgets(word,sizeof(word),dict) == NULL)
            break;
        char *cp = strchr(word,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (n == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(n->word, word);

        word_count++;

        // Index word using hash function
        int dict_index = hash(word);

        n->next = table[dict_index];

        table[dict_index] = n;
    }

    // Close dictionary file
    fclose(dict);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int
size(void)
{
    return word_count;
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool
unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        node *cursor = table[i];

        while (cursor) {
            node *tmp = cursor;

            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Although the above code is [now] correct, it can be further improved.

For some additional fixes and speedups, see my cs50 speller answer: [cs50 pset5 Speller optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316468/5382650)

Here is a comparison of the elapsed time for the `check` function between your [fixed] version vs my [optimized] version from the link:

```
 Yours       Mine     File
 27.900433   0.271936 aca.txt
  8.713822   0.093062 austen.txt
  1.553954   0.015378 birdman.txt
  3.996230   0.041159 burnett.txt
  1.927505   0.021139 carroll.txt
  0.001437   0.000007 cat.txt
  0.477209   0.005412 constitution.txt
 12.684350   0.141040 federalist.txt
  5.947873   0.060730 frankenstein.txt
  6.810451   0.081574 grimm.txt
  1.279325   0.013508 her.txt
 78.311622   0.861220 holmes.txt
 14.265868   0.145593 homer.txt
  1.297946   0.013600 lalaland.txt
  4.110416   0.042714 mansfield.txt
  0.002796   0.000017 pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.txt
  1.739467   0.017283 revenant.txt
  5.238748   0.054731 rinehart.txt
 68.048034   0.680697 shakespeare.txt
  6.071052   0.064508 stein.txt
 11.721317   0.121086 stoker.txt
 14.137166   0.146902 surgery.txt
 40.615153   0.433262 tolstoy.txt
  9.731160   0.099112 wells.txt
 39.266734   0.457958 whittier.txt
  0.014416   0.000132 wordsworth.txt
 13.774792   0.144299 xueqin1.txt
 18.768864   0.196494 xueqin2.txt
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! My code hit 7 out of 9 check points and I just submitted that code because I couldn't figure it out and whenever I changed it it stopped compiling, so I kinda just gave up but your code helped me learn a lot and also fixed my code so thank you!