# hashmap not recognizing identical keys

Tags: c, hashmap

I've been trying to use a hashmap for a while now, using code that my instructor provided, but it just simply cannot recognize two identical characters as being the same.

I'm really not sure what more I can say about it-I've tried modifying my code and the instructors, tried various different ways of sending the parameters, all sorts of other things that I can't quite remember off of the top of my head. It just doesn't seem to recognize that 'a' = 'a'.

My relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hash.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);

    hashmap map = hash_init();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char cha = argv[1][i];

        put(&map, cha, 1);
    }

    char* mapStr = to_str(map);
    printf("%s", mapStr);

    return 0;
}
```

my instructor's relevant code:

hashmap.c

```
#include "hash.h"

hashmap hash_init(void) {
    hashmap h = {(map_node **)malloc(BINS * sizeof(map_node *)), 0, BINS};
    for (int i = 0; i < BINS; i++)
        h.table[i] = NULL;
    return h;
}

static int hash(char *key, int bins) {
    unsigned hashval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
        hashval = 31 * hashval + key[i];
    return hashval % bins;
}

int put(hashmap *h, char *key, int value) {
    int index = hash(key, h->bins);
    for (map_node *iterator = h->table[index]; iterator; iterator = iterator->next)
        if (!strcmp(iterator->key, key)){// I found the key
            int old_val = iterator->value;
            iterator->value = value;
            return old_val;//return old value
        }
    if (h->size >= h->bins)//load factor >= 100%
        rehash(h);
    map_node *new_element = (map_node *)malloc(sizeof(map_node));
    new_element->next = h->table[index];
    new_element->key = strdup(key);
    new_element->value = value;
    h->table[index] = new_element;
    h->size++;
    return 0;//return old value
}

char* to_str(hashmap h){
    char* rv = (char*) malloc(h.size * 100 + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < h.bins;i++)
        for (map_node *it = h.table[i]; it; it = it->next)
            sprintf(rv, "%s\n%s: %d", rv, it->key, it->value);
    return rv;
}
```

```
Input: abcba
expected output: a:2 b:2 c:1
actual output: b:1 b:1 c:1 a:1 a:1
```

Thank you for at least reading this.

Comment: you should get compiler error that `put` expects `char*`, but you're sending `char`

Comment: replace `char cha = argv[1][i];` with `char cha[2]{ argv[1][i], 0 };`

Comment: @IłyaBursov: Is that a C++ initialization? This question is not tagged C++. Or did you omit an `=`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah, tested with c++ compiler, should be with `=`

Comment: The second argument to `put()`string. You can't send a single character, because a string requires a null terminator. So you need to create a 1-character string that contains the character from `argv[1][i]`.

Comment: _Side note:_ Your instructor's code is awful. Passing around/returning a `struct` by _value_ is to be avoided. The `to_str` is slow (it recopies the ever increasing `rv` each iteration). And, _may_ be UB. Hardwire of `100`? Using an extra pointer, this fixes the _worst_: `char *to_str(hashmap h) { char *rv = malloc(h.size * 100 + 1); char *rp = rv; *rp = 0; for (int i = 0; i < h.bins; i++) for (map_node * it = h.table[i]; it; it = it->next) rp += sprintf(rp, "%s: %d\n", it->key, it->value); return rv; }`

Comment: For some comparison of hashmaps, here's an answer of mine: [cs50 pset5 Speller optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316468/5382650)

Comment: Input is a command line argument, and the output has a newline after each key not space separated.

Comment: @Ilya Bursov, Eric Postpischil, Thanks for the fix, it works properly now. And thanks Barmar for explaining why. I really should've known, since my last assignment was all about working with '/0'. I'll look into following everyone else's advice, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is incomplete without hash.h.  This means that I had to add missing includes, reverse engineer the typedef `map_node`, `hashmap`.  Make up a value for `BINS`.  Create a placeholder for the function `rehash()`.
2. (Not fixed) Prefer using a consistent namespace prefix on all symbols that might be exported (types, functions, global variables).  `hash_` xor `hashmap_`?
3. Avoid global variables (`BINS`).  In this case just add that as  argument to `hash_init()`.
4. (Not fixed) `hash_init()`: returns the `hashmap` by value.  As the return value could be large you are better off returning a `hashmap *`.  This means you need to allocate both a `hashmap` and `hashmap.table`.
5. `hash_init()`: Prefer `calloc()` to `malloc()` + `for()`.
6. Don't cast `void *` like from `malloc()`.
7. Prefer `sizeof var` to `sizeof(type)`. The former is a purely mechanical transformation, and variable is usually shorter (i.e. no namespace prefix) than the type name.  For example:

   ```
   map_node *new_element = malloc(sizeof *new_element)
   ```
8. Instead of calculating the length of a string with `strlen()`, particular a loop, use the fact that `str[i]` is false on terminating `\0`.  So instead of `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)` do `for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++)`.
9. `put()`: Either lookup the existing value of a key and call `put(...,  old_value + 1)` with your existing implementation, allow collisions for the same key to be chained via the `next` pointer and rework `hashmap_print()` to sum them up per unique keys, or update the value for same key.  I fixed `put()` to achieve the latter here as that seems to be the approach you were using.
10. `put()`: If you `rehash()` then `index` is no longer valid for the subsequent insert.  Either do it first or last, or call `hash()` after `rehash()` if you really want to do it in the the middle.
11. `to_str()`: `sprintf(rv, ..., rv, ...)` is undefined behavior as you just print it anyways changed it to `hashmap_print()`.
12. `main()`: check `argc` before you deference `argv`.
13. `main()`: `put()` expects a string but `argv[1][i]` is a `char`.  It's undefined behavior to pass a non-\0 terminated string to `strlen()`.  Construct a string, for example, using an initializer.
14. (Not fixed) Make sure you free all memory allocated.  If nothing else so you have a clean slate for when you need to look for leaks.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct map_node {
    char *key;
    int value;
    struct map_node *next;
} map_node;

typedef struct {
    map_node **table;
    int size;
    int bins;
} hashmap;

int BINS = 13;

hashmap hash_init(void) {
    return (hashmap) { calloc(BINS, sizeof(map_node *)), 0, BINS };
}

static int hash(char *key, int bins) {
    unsigned hashval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; key[i]; i++)
        hashval = 31 * hashval + key[i];
    return hashval % bins;
}

void rehash(hashmap *h) {
    assert("TBD" && 0);
}

int put(hashmap *h, char *key, int value) {
    if (h->size >= h->bins)
        rehash(h);
    int index = hash(key, h->bins);
    for (map_node *iterator = h->table[index]; iterator; iterator = iterator->next)
        if (!strcmp(iterator->key, key)){
            int old_value = iterator->value;
            iterator->value += value;
            return old_value;
        }
    map_node *new_element = malloc(sizeof *new_element);
    new_element->next = h->table[index];
    new_element->key = strdup(key);
    new_element->value = value;
    h->table[index] = new_element;
    h->size++;
    return 0;
}

void hashmap_print(hashmap *h){
    for(int i = 0; i < h->bins;i++)
        for (map_node *it = h->table[i]; it; it = it->next)
            printf("%s: %d\n", it->key, it->value);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: program keys\n");
        return 1;
    }
    hashmap map = hash_init();
    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
        put(&map, (char []) { argv[1][i], '\0' }, 1);
    hashmap_print(&map);
}
```

and example run:

```
$ ./a.out abcba
a: 2
b: 2
c: 1
```

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.